# Angular.JS onclick function only called on first click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on a small aplication using Angular.JS
In my view i have following button

```
<md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="editUser(user, $event)">Edit</md-button>
```

the editUser method looks something like this:

```
$scope.editUser = function (user, $event) {

    $scope.userToEdit = user;

    $mdDialog.show({
            controller: DialogController,
            targetEvent: $event,
            templateUrl: '/js/modules/user/views/edit.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            scope: $scope
        })
        .
        then(function (answer) {
            if (answer == "save") {
                for (right in $scope.allSystemRightsStatements) {
                    if ($scope.allSystemRightsStatements[right].selected) {
                        if( $scope.userToEdit.rights==null){
                            $scope.userToEdit.rights = [];
                        }
                        $scope.userToEdit.rights.push($scope.allSystemRightsStatements[right]);
                    }
                }
                $scope.updateUser($scope.userToEdit);
            }
            $scope.userToEdit = {};
        }, function () {
            $scope.userToEdit = {};
        });
};

$scope.updateUser = function (user) {
    //userService.updateUser makes a $http PUT request
    var promise = userService.updateUser(user);
    promise.then(function (result) {
        $mdToast.show(
            $mdToast.simple(result.message)
                .position($scope.getToastPosition())
                .hideDelay(3000)
        );
    }, function (reason) {
        $mdToast.show(
            $mdToast.simple(reason)
                .position($scope.getToastPosition())
                .hideDelay(3000)
        );
    }, function (update) {
    });
};
```

Now the dialog is nicely shown and the answer function is also called, everything as expected.

However, when I click the button a second time the editUser funciton is not executed. As if the onClick event from the button had been removed at dialog close.

Any help on solving this problem is greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: do you see any error in the console log?

Comment: your error could be in the **..some small logic** part of your code...

It could also be due to the fact, that you are calling an async method with `$scope.updateUser` and then immediatly setting `$scope.userToEdit` to an empy object. `$scope.updateUser` might not have had the time to finish what it was intend to do and you set the passed object to an empty object...

Comment: No console log is empty :-( 
The update is actually performed correctly (as reflected by the DB). I'll add the small logic for clarification.

Comment: Does DialogController contains a definition of editUser as well?

Comment: No I pass the original scope to the dialogController, which already has the userToEdit in it. The DialogController does not have any logic apart from the standard hide, cancel and answer methods (only calling the respective $mdDialog.* function).

Comment: I asked because, as you are passing the scope, you may be overriding the editUser method with something with the new controller

Comment: if you put a console.log(user) right after `function (user, $event) {`, does it even logs something?

Comment: No the function is not called the second time. only on the first click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1531#issuecomment-74813190)

> it is probably a good idea to explicitly mention that the scope will be destroyed upon hiding the dialog (so people shouldn't pass a controller's $scope directly).

(regarding the scope you are passing to mdDialog)

So, as the scope is destroyed, angular is not binding your button with any action

Comment: For clarification: i removed `scope: $scope` from the `$mdDialog.show` call and added `locals: {user: user, .. other objects}`